# How to replace index by variable from for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my telemetry data table change color depend on value in table. In this platform they give the index to point to telemetry data like "${#0}" (0 is number of data).Then I just create table and put them inside my table to show the telemetry data. But I need the background color of each value change,such as when the value is "0" the backgroud of that value change to orange. When the value is "1" backgroud = green. The easiest way  is write if-else condition for every value in table. But my code will have too many character. I want to use for loop or while loop to loop check value in the table.And I need the value in loop to replace my index number that point to each telemetry data (to check every value in table and change the background color) But when I put the value in for loop to my index. It doesn't work. Nothings happen. Anyone can help how to fix it? Thanks:)

`````````
<div class="divTable minimalistBlack">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Header-->
            <div class="divTableHead">STATION</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">ENTITY TYPE</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">ATS</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">FAULT</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">FEEDER1</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">SW1</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">FEEDER2</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">SW2</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">ACTIVE STATUS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 1-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 1</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="0" div class="divTableCell">${#0}</div>
            <div id="1" div class="divTableCell">${#1}</div>
            <div id="2" div class="divTableCell">${#2}</div>
            <div id="3" div class="divTableCell">${#3}</div>
            <div id="4" div class="divTableCell">${#4}</div>
            <div id="5" div class="divTableCell">${#5}</div>
            <div id="6" div class="divTableCell">${#6}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 2-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 2</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="7" div class="divTableCell">${#7}</div>
            <div id="8" div class="divTableCell">${#8}</div>
            <div id="9" div class="divTableCell">${#9}</div>
            <div id="10" div class="divTableCell">${#10}</div>
            <div id="11" div class="divTableCell">${#11}</div>
            <div id="12" div class="divTableCell">${#12}</div>
            <div id="13" div class="divTableCell">${#13}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 3-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 3</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="14" div class="divTableCell">${#14}</div>
            <div id="15" div class="divTableCell">${#15}</div>
            <div id="16" div class="divTableCell">${#16}</div>
            <div id="17" div class="divTableCell">${#17}</div>
            <div id="28" div class="divTableCell">${#18}</div>
            <div id="19" div class="divTableCell">${#19}</div>
            <div id="20" div class="divTableCell">${#20}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 4-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 4</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="21" div class="divTableCell">${#21}</div>
            <div id="22" div class="divTableCell">${#22}</div>
            <div id="23" div class="divTableCell">${#23}</div>
            <div id="24" div class="divTableCell">${#24}</div>
            <div id="25" div class="divTableCell">${#25}</div>
            <div id="26" div class="divTableCell">${#26}</div>
            <div id="27" div class="divTableCell">${#27}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 5-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 5</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="28" div class="divTableCell">${#28}</div>
            <div id="29" div class="divTableCell">${#29}</div>
            <div id="30" div class="divTableCell">${#30}</div>
            <div id="31" div class="divTableCell">${#31}</div>
            <div id="32" div class="divTableCell">${#32}</div>
            <div id="33" div class="divTableCell">${#33}</div>
            <div id="34" div class="divTableCell">${#34}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 6-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 6</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="35" div class="divTableCell">${#35}</div>
            <div id="36" div class="divTableCell">${#36}</div>
            <div id="37" div class="divTableCell">${#37}</div>
            <div id="38" div class="divTableCell">${#38}</div>
            <div id="39" div class="divTableCell">${#39}</div>
            <div id="40" div class="divTableCell">${#40}</div>
            <div id="41" div class="divTableCell">${#41}</div>
        </div>
        <script>
                (function () {
                    int  i = 0;
                    while(i<42){
                    if (${#i} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#i} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                            }
                        i++;
                        }
                    })();    
                </script>
        </div>
    </div>


````````



**This is my original code that I wnat to make it fewer characters.**


````````
<div class="divTable minimalistBlack">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Header-->
            <div class="divTableHead">STATION</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">ENTITY TYPE</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">ATS</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">FAULT</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">FEEDER1</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">SW1</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">FEEDER2</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">SW2</div>
            <div class="divTableHead">ACTIVE STATUS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 1-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 1</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="0" div class="divTableCell">${#0}</div>
            <div id="1" div class="divTableCell">${#1}</div>
            <div id="2" div class="divTableCell">${#2}</div>
            <div id="3" div class="divTableCell">${#3}</div>
            <div id="4" div class="divTableCell">${#4}</div>
            <div id="5" div class="divTableCell">${#5}</div>
            <div id="6" div class="divTableCell">${#6}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 2-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 2</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="7" div class="divTableCell">${#7}</div>
            <div id="8" div class="divTableCell">${#8}</div>
            <div id="9" div class="divTableCell">${#9}</div>
            <div id="10" div class="divTableCell">${#10}</div>
            <div id="11" div class="divTableCell">${#11}</div>
            <div id="12" div class="divTableCell">${#12}</div>
            <div id="13" div class="divTableCell">${#13}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 3-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 3</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="14" div class="divTableCell">${#14}</div>
            <div id="15" div class="divTableCell">${#15}</div>
            <div id="16" div class="divTableCell">${#16}</div>
            <div id="17" div class="divTableCell">${#17}</div>
            <div id="18" div class="divTableCell">${#18}</div>
            <div id="19" div class="divTableCell">${#19}</div>
            <div id="20" div class="divTableCell">${#20}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 4-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 4</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="21" div class="divTableCell">${#21}</div>
            <div id="22" div class="divTableCell">${#22}</div>
            <div id="23" div class="divTableCell">${#23}</div>
            <div id="24" div class="divTableCell">${#24}</div>
            <div id="25" div class="divTableCell">${#25}</div>
            <div id="26" div class="divTableCell">${#26}</div>
            <div id="27" div class="divTableCell">${#27}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 5-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 5</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="28" div class="divTableCell">${#28}</div>
            <div id="29" div class="divTableCell">${#29}</div>
            <div id="30" div class="divTableCell">${#30}</div>
            <div id="31" div class="divTableCell">${#31}</div>
            <div id="32" div class="divTableCell">${#32}</div>
            <div id="33" div class="divTableCell">${#33}</div>
            <div id="34" div class="divTableCell">${#34}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow"> <!--Row 6-->
            <div class="divTableCell">Station 6</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
            <div id="35" div class="divTableCell">${#35}</div>
            <div id="36" div class="divTableCell">${#36}</div>
            <div id="37" div class="divTableCell">${#37}</div>
            <div id="38" div class="divTableCell">${#38}</div>
            <div id="39" div class="divTableCell">${#39}</div>
            <div id="40" div class="divTableCell">${#40}</div>
            <div id="41" div class="divTableCell">${#41}</div>
        </div>
        <script>
                (function () {
                    if (${#0} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(0).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#0} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(0).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#1} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(1).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#1} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(1).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#2} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(2).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#2} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(2).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#3} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(3).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#3} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(3).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#4} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(4).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#4} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(4).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#5} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(5).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#5} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(5).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#6} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(6).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#6} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(6).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#7} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(7).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#7} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(7).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#8} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(8).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#8} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(8).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#9} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(9).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#9} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(9).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#10} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(10).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#10} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(10).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#11} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(11).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#11} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(11).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#12} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(12).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#12} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(12).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#13} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(13).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#13} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(13).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#14} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(14).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#14} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(14).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#15} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(15).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#15} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(15).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#16} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(16).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#16} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(16).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#17} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(17).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#17} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(17).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#18} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(18).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#18} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(18).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#19} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(19).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#19} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(19).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#20} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(20).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#20} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(20).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#21} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(21).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#21} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(21).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#22} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(22).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#22} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(22).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#23} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(23).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#23} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(23).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#24} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(24).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#24} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(24).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#25} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(25).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#25} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(25).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#26} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(26).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#26} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(26).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#27} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(27).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }    
                    else if (${#27} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(27).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#28} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(28).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#28} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(28).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#29} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(29).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#29} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(29).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#30} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(30).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#30} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(30).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#31} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(31).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#31} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(31).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#32} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(32).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#32} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(32).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#33} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(33).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#33} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(33).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }    
                    if (${#34} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(34).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#34} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(34).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#35} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(35).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#35} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(35).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#36} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(36).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#36} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(36).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#37} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(37).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#37} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(37).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#38} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(38).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#38} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(38).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#39} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(39).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#39} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(39).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#40} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(40).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#40} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(40).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                    if (${#41} == 0) {
                        document.getElementById(41).style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
                        }
                    else if (${#41} == 1){
                        document.getElementById(41).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
                        }
                })();    
            </script>
    </div>
</div>

````````
`````````

Comment: The problem is you never increment the value of i, you just assign it to zero over and over again.

Comment: Why do you need a loop if you need a different background only for id `0` and `1`? Also, `${#i}` is invalid syntax. You need to use `$('#' + i)` or template literals `$(\`#${i}\`)`. Please use a code editor which highlights these obvious errors

Comment: Yes.I forge to add i++; Already add. @Tatarize but Still doesn't work

Comment: You still have the line `i = 0;` at the end. Even if you briefly made it equal to 1 you instantly reset it zero.

Comment: Well, I'm done. But, lemme tell you. You need to just use a CSS on that. And change the color of the them according to that. I've got no clue why some of them get `#99C262` or '#F8D347' and a loop is kinda pointless if you're only coloring them the one way just add that information to the HTML. --- I came to this question during triage and figured it looked ok because I could see how the while loop screwy, but I think I voted wrong because I have no idea what you're trying to do or why.

Comment: I make a dashboard for monitoring real-time data from remote station. I made this in Thingsboard platform. But they don't have any table that I want. So I need to create that by modify the widget by myself. Only one way to fecth data to table is use there index `(${#...})`. You said I can use CSS  to change the color. Can you give advice to use CSS to change color of box depend on dynamic value in the table please. I 'm beginner with CSS&JS. Thanks! @Tatarize

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside @adiga's point that this is weird and I'm not sure why you think this is how you do this. Here's a successful loop for the data with `i++` each loop

```js
(function() {
  //initialized i
  var i = 0;
  while (i++ < 42) { //incrementing i each time
    element = document.getElementById(i)
    if (element == null) continue;
    text = element.textContent;
    if ('${#' + i + '}' == text) {
       element.style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
    }
    //not resetting i to 0 here
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="divTable minimalistBlack">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Header-->
      <div class="divTableHead">STATION</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">ENTITY TYPE</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">ATS</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">FAULT</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">FEEDER1</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">SW1</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">FEEDER2</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">SW2</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">ACTIVE STATUS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Row 1-->
      <div class="divTableCell">Station 1</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
      <div id="0" div class="divTableCell">${#0}</div>
      <div id="1" div class="divTableCell">${#1}</div>
      <div id="2" div class="divTableCell">${#2}</div>
      <div id="3" div class="divTableCell">${#3}</div>
      <div id="4" div class="divTableCell">${#4}</div>
      <div id="5" div class="divTableCell">${#5}</div>
      <div id="6" div class="divTableCell">${#6}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Row 2-->
      <div class="divTableCell">Station 2</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
      <div id="7" div class="divTableCell">${#7}</div>
      <div id="8" div class="divTableCell">${#8}</div>
      <div id="9" div class="divTableCell">${#9}</div>
      <div id="10" div class="divTableCell">${#10}</div>
      <div id="11" div class="divTableCell">${#11}</div>
      <div id="12" div class="divTableCell">${#12}</div>
      <div id="13" div class="divTableCell">${#13}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Row 3-->
      <div class="divTableCell">Station 3</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
      <div id="14" div class="divTableCell">${#14}</div>
      <div id="15" div class="divTableCell">${#15}</div>
      <div id="16" div class="divTableCell">${#16}</div>
      <div id="17" div class="divTableCell">${#17}</div>
      <div id="28" div class="divTableCell">${#18}</div>
      <div id="19" div class="divTableCell">${#19}</div>
      <div id="20" div class="divTableCell">${#20}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Row 4-->
      <div class="divTableCell">Station 4</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
      <div id="21" div class="divTableCell">${#21}</div>
      <div id="22" div class="divTableCell">${#22}</div>
      <div id="23" div class="divTableCell">${#23}</div>
      <div id="24" div class="divTableCell">${#24}</div>
      <div id="25" div class="divTableCell">${#25}</div>
      <div id="26" div class="divTableCell">${#26}</div>
      <div id="27" div class="divTableCell">${#27}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Row 5-->
      <div class="divTableCell">Station 5</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
      <div id="28" div class="divTableCell">${#28}</div>
      <div id="29" div class="divTableCell">${#29}</div>
      <div id="30" div class="divTableCell">${#30}</div>
      <div id="31" div class="divTableCell">${#31}</div>
      <div id="32" div class="divTableCell">${#32}</div>
      <div id="33" div class="divTableCell">${#33}</div>
      <div id="34" div class="divTableCell">${#34}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <!--Row 6-->
      <div class="divTableCell">Station 6</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">DEVICE</div>
      <div id="35" div class="divTableCell">${#35}</div>
      <div id="36" div class="divTableCell">${#36}</div>
      <div id="37" div class="divTableCell">${#37}</div>
      <div id="38" div class="divTableCell">${#38}</div>
      <div id="39" div class="divTableCell">${#39}</div>
      <div id="40" div class="divTableCell">${#40}</div>
      <div id="41" div class="divTableCell">${#41}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I already add my original code that I want to make it fewer character. Can you consider it.Thanks:) @Tatarize